# Removing focus indicator from RecycleView in Android

Tags: android, focus, android-recyclerview

I have an app using `RecyclerView`, and on the tablet I get a light blue background showing.  Particularly on Jelly Bean devices and in the emulator.  I've tried to remove it by marking my `RecyclerView` as `android:focusable="false"`  I know it's the focus indicator since on the emulator if I hit the tab key it goes away and highlights a button on the UI.  It doesn't show up on the phones I've used.

So why is it being rendered on a touch device?  And how do I get rid of it?

Comment: do you try set **android:focusable="false"** to parent view that represent item of list?

Comment: I added it to RecycleView directly.  Not the items within the list.  When it draws the focus indicator it's always over the entire list and not just a single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the style of your recyclerView item. Use `selectors`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressedStateColor" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/focusedStateColor" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/normalStateColor" />
</selector>
```

If you don't what any color to show just give the same color to the focused state or try `"@android:color/transparent"`.

Then set your `android:background="@drawable/your_above_xml"`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But why does it show the RecycleView as being focused on tablets and on phones it doesn't do it?  And if I set my RecycleView to be focusable=false why would that state still be shown?

Comment: @chubbsondubs if this solved please mark it as it. But regarding your question I'm assuming your tablet is KitKay or lower so the ripple effect isn't present and you get that opaque "selected" color.

Comment: Yes the tablet is Jelly Bean, and yes it's a solid light blue color.  The only issue I have this answer is turning it off at the style level seems unnecessary if I mark a component as focusable = "false".  If the component isn't focusable then it shouldn't be in that state.

Comment: But this is indeed a style issue. The blue color you are seeing is the default JellyBean theme color, hence the selector.

Comment: If the component isn't focusable why is it showing up?  If it can't receive focus then the style of how focus is drawn shouldn't come into play.

Comment: It was marked clickable.  But turning both of them off didn't seem to fix it either.  I'm beginning to think this is a bug so I ended up using your style change to turn it off entirely.  So it ended up being the workaround needed.

Comment: Then please Mark it as the accepted answer (SO policy). You could try to search your View hierarchy if there is a view being clicked on the rv item layout